# Problem with a bluetooth speaker

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 16.04

I have just reinstalled to OS on my laptop due to upgrading to an SSD and switched from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. I was surprised that my bluetooth speaker stopped working in a stable way, like it was working with 14.04. Now I wave to go through all these steps to make it work:

1. Turn on the speaker (doesn't auto-connect like it did in 14.04)
2. Turn on the speaker in the Bluetooth settings (doesn't play music, it just doesn't start playing at all)
3. In sound settings for the speaker change mode from A2DP to HSP/HFP (it starts playing music, but in very low quality)
4. Change the mode back to A2DP (it automatically switches to built in speakers each time I choose the Bluetooth speaker and try to change the mode back to A2DP)
5. Turn of the speaker and turn it on again
6. Only now it lets you switch the mode for the Bluetooth speaker back to A2DP and plays music

By "plays music" I literally mean it - it doesn't start the playback.

Does anyone have any advice how to deal with this problem?

Comment: I have a similar issue -- I have a lot of trouble getting my bluetooth speaker to work after upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

I have exactly the same problem you are describing, when I choose A2DP mode while my bluetooth speaker is selected I automatically get switched to the built in audio while in the sound menu.

Sometimes If I switch to A2DP during playback whatever I am playing freezes and does not start to play until I select something else.

I often get it working after some tinkering with restarting my bluetooth speaker and disconnecting/connecting the bluetooth.