# No sound from Bluetooth headphones since Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: sound, 16.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I have Nakamichi bluetooth headphones that have synced successfully with the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS on my computer. The playing mode even comes up as A2DP in the sound options. When you try to test sound (LEFT and RIGHT channels), nothing happens. It was working prior to 16.04 LTS and these headphones work on OS X (yes I have a mac) and with my Android smartphone.

If I do a hard reset of the headphones and the computer, sometimes i can get everything working again after 15 minutes. It shouldn't be this arduous though. I think there must be a bug in which everything pairs but no sound comes out as a result. I have everything cranked up to maximum via pavucontrol and nothing seems to be working properly. I could use some assistance with the issue.

[image: Sound Settings]

This is the picture of it paired however there is no audio coming out of it whatsoever. I read someplace else that this is a known issue. I'll update this post once I find that link.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you post a screenshot of *System Settings → Audio* while the thing is not working? Also, a screenshot of the terminal while `alsamixer` is running might be useful.

Comment: How do you hard reset your headphones?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using HSP/HFP. A lot of people have the same issue with A2DP.

- [Distorted sound with bluetooth speaker in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760223/distorted-sound-with-bluetooth-speaker-in-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1)
- [After updating to 16.04, bluetooth audio A2DP mode stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working)

  - [Problem with a bluetooth speaker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765367/problem-with-a-bluetooth-speaker?rq=1)